# How to import third party module dynamically on demand in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-splitting, recharts

I'm currently working on reducing vendor size of react project. I've reduced significant size in lodash and moment and now I want to import dynamically for [recharts](https://github.com/recharts/recharts).
I'm importing some components of recharts like this -

```
import {ResponsiveContainer, LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid } from 'recharts';
```

I've tried cherry-pick method like this for each of them -

```
import ResponsiveContainer from 'recharts/es6/component/ResponsiveContainer';
import LineChart from 'recharts/es6/chart/LineChart';
```

But it doesn't change anything in vendor bundle.

I'd like to know whether there is a way to import dynamically on demand for third party library or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try dynamic imports as part of esNext Module. import('./widgets').then(m=>m.WidgetModule)

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Another thing I want to know is that will recharts package still include in vendor bundle if I use such dynamic import? I saw seperate bundles of those recharts components  when I tried that ```import('recharts/..')```

Comment: I don't think you can do dynamic imports for Vendor packages. only Application specific files can be dynamically imported.